# Angular avoid Route parameter (:id) and navigate to specific link

Tags: angular, routes, auth-guard, routeparams

In our project, I have to implement a navigation or redirect to a maintenance page, if maintenance mode is activated.
I wanted to do this in the AuthGuard service, and do something like:

```
canActivate(...) {
    if (this.inMaintenance()) {        
    this._navController.navigateForward('settings-maintenance', { replaceUrl: true });
    return false;
    }
}
```

unfortunately, the project routes settings are like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./template/template.module').then((module) => 
    module.TemplatePageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},    
{
    path: 'settings-maintenance',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: SMaintenanceComponent,
},
{
    path: ':id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./template/template.module').then((module) => 
    module.TemplatePageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},
{
    path: ':id/:params',
    loadChildren: () => import('./template/template.module').then((module) => module.TemplatePageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},
];
```

so, whenever I try to navigate to settings-maintenance, it will hit the route-guard again because it thinks it is `path: ':id'`. Is there a way to avoid this?
I wanted to avoid to show the login page and directly redirect to the SMaintenance Page without login, but no Idea how to do it..
Otherwise, I will have to check for maintenance mode in the footer or so and then do a redirect there after the login...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, all of your paths will match to the first empty path. You always need to include `pathMatch: 'full'` with an empty path, or it will match to anything and everything. I suppose nobody has noticed because they all load the same module....

```js
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./template/template.module').then((module) => 
    module.TemplatePageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
...
```

It should check for path matches in order, so it will find the maintenance page before the :id page.

Doc reference: https://angular.io/api/router/Route

> The path-match strategy 'full' matches against the entire URL. It is important to do this when redirecting empty-path routes. Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop.

An empty path without `pathMatch: 'full'` usually appears as the last route, and is used to catch any routes that don't exist, either redirecting or displaying a 404 page.